# How to get current settings from the android phone using kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, wallpaper, ringtone, android-vibration

How can we get current user settings like phone ringtone & ring volume, Current wallpaper, vibration, etc setting programmatically?

I want to store them & set them back whenever user wants to.....

I am new to kotlin.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code for your purpose.

**For getting ringtone:**

```
val defaultRingtoneUri = RingtoneManager.getActualDefaultRingtoneUri(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE)
        val defaultRingtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getActivity(), defaultRingtoneUri)
```

**For getting ringtone volume:**

```
  val am = getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager
        val volume_level = am.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)
```

**For getting current wallpaper:**

```
 val  wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this) as WallpaperManager
            val wallpaperDrawable: Drawable = wallpaperManager.getDrawable()
```

Comment: How can I set them back ? Do i need to save `defaultRingtone` as file? or I can get file path to set it back?

Comment: u will get file path and u can set it back setRingtone method..use sharepref to store data or local database..u can also use file also as u mentioned

Answer (score 0):

For [Ringtone](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/RingtoneManager.html) you can use RingtoneManager and get the default ringtone with `RingtoneManager.getActualDefaultRingtoneUri(Context context, int type)`

For [Volume](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#setStreamVolume%28int,%20int,%20int%29) you can use AudioManager.

```
AudioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING)
```

For [Wallpaper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html#getWallpaperInfo()) you can user WallpaperManager.

```
WallpaperManager.getDrawable() -> //Retrieve the current system wallpaper.
```

If you need any other information please try to use stackoverflow search function or simply google search.

Good luck!